# Problem integrating Angular SPA and mongodb in heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, heroku

I am creating a simple app using angular and I am trying to use mongodb to save my data. So far I managed to create my SPA with angular and deploy it to heroku adding the server.js file. My problem starts when I tried to connect mongodb.

Currently I was serving my page using

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/showoff/index.html'));
});
```

Inside index.html I am calling `<app-root>` and my application has two routes: `/display` and `/control`

I then realized I have to add some more routes to save and read from my database through a service, so I had to add things like:

```
router.route('/players').get((req, res) => {
    Player.find((err, player) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(player);
    });
});
```

Problem is that I cant reach those routes since I have already one with `/*`. I tried writing this other routes on top as I figured it might take the first it finds but its not working and I am always redirected to my index.html

My question is:

Is there a way to deploy my SPA like this and still use mongo? or do I need to somehow restructure everything since my approach isn't right?

You can find my whole code here if needed [GitHub code](https://github.com/CheDragon/showoffscores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone I did the following. Not sure if its the best way to go but it worked.

I divided my `/*` route as follows

```
app.get('/display', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/showoff/index.html'));
});

app.get('/control', function(req,res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/dist/showoff/index.html'));
});
```

And continue to add handlers for other routes there, which manage the requests to write and read from the database.